# Can I use redirect or render as a way to "refresh" the current web page I'm on in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if I can use the redirect()/render() function and point to the default page (http://127.0.0.1:8000) as a way to essentially refresh the page I'm on.  I feel like it'd work but I'm not sure what to put in the parameters of the function, I've seen people say redirect("/path/") but that gives me an error the second I click my submission button. as well as if I need to change anything elsewhere within the framework.  I also know you can return multiple items in python, but can I return the original item as well as a call to redirect()/render()?

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .forms import FileFieldForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .perform_conversion import FileConverter
import zipfile
import io


def FileFieldFormView(request, *args, **kwargs):
 
    form = FileFieldForm(request.POST)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request)
        form = FileFieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

        
            zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()   
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "w", False) as zip_file:
            
                for f in files:
                    fileconverter = FileConverter(f.name)
                    fileconverter.run(f.file)
                
                    for img_name, img in fileconverter.output.items():
                
                        data = io.BytesIO(img)
                    
                        zip_file.writestr(img_name, data.getvalue())
            
            # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
            response = HttpResponse(zip_buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
            # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
            response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % 'zip.zip'
            response.set_signed_cookie('csrftoken', request.COOKIES['csrftoken'])
        
        
            # Return the response value
            return response

            
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form Invalid')

    else:
        return render(request, 'file_converter.html')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to refresh the active django webpage without using return redirect(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72968167/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-the-active-django-webpage-without-using-return-redirec)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `name` for path in `urls.py` and call redirect with that name in suitable function returns. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/) will help you

Comment: In order for the file to work correctly, the response value has to be returned since it's the zip file.  In doing this will that value still be getting returned? Or will that only accomplish the refresh part.  Any extra clarification/code/examples would be much appreciated, I'm a super novice when it comes to django so I'm still fairly unsure about what to do.